# How to define region template, and render it in page.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I want to separate the header and footer wiht 2 tpl files with region, for avoid to write code repeatedly.

That is my directory structure  :

```
├── style.css
├── template.php
├── templates
│   ├── html.tpl.php
│   ├── pages
│   │   └── page--front.tpl.php
│   ├── regions
│   │   └── region--header.tpl.php
│   └── views
└── yuanjie.info
```

I add some test text in `region--header.tpl.php`:

```
testtest
```

and render it in `page--front.tpl.php`:

```
<?php print render($page['header']) ?>
```

The I clean the cache, and refresh the front page, not work.

Comment: Try moving all of your template files directly to the root templates folder, instead of placing it in sub-directories. You have not specified which theme you are using. I think by default it will look for template files directly in templates folder and only some themes change the theme registry to look in sub-folders.

Comment: Move all the template files directly under the template directory and check for the variables in template.php are accodding to the theme.